# Can't run my code in codeblocks for ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdoAN.png)
[image]
 I try to press yes but it still doesn't run

Comment: There's no information whatsoever that could let us even guess what the problem is. Maybe you haven't setup the IDE properly to use the compiler, maybe you don't even have a compiler installed?

Comment: can you compile that code??? did you try compiling 1st????

Comment: Hello Kien. Please add some additional information that you tried. Consider this when asking questions here at stackoverflow.com [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this is that your default MinGW folder directory saved on CodeBlocks from a fresh install is incorrect. To correct that issue, or to check if that is the problem, follow these steps:

> ***settings -> compiler and debugger -> toolchains executables tab -> Auto-detect***

This should correctly detect the correct directory for the MinGW folder so that CodeBlocks can access the compiler.